# RTSP video plays fine on Wowza test player but unable to play video if tested on VLC or other players (audio always plays fine)

Tags: video-streaming, audio-streaming, rtsp, wowza, rtsp-client

I am working on An RTSP based application in which i am trying to broadcast my mac screen to a wowza using rtsp. Everything seems to be working fine but i am facing some very very strange issues while broadcasting the audio and video on wowza.

What i am doing is that capturing the audio from external mic and capturing the screen on the mac and converting it into video and than broadcast the audio and video as separate streams.

If i broadcast both audio and video to wowza than in that case the video and audio both plays fine on wowza test players (comes with wowza client). but if i tries to stream the same stream to vlc player (using RTSP or RTMP) or any other online HLS players only Audio plays fine but video doesn't plays at all.

But if i independently broadcast the video stream (without audio) it works perfectly fine without any issues.

Can anyone who faces the same issues or have experience in RTSP broadcast help me in sorting out the issue and finding a solution for this issue.

ADDED the log of VLC..

```
main debug: VLC media player - 2.1.2 Rincewind
main debug: Copyright ¬© 1996-2013 the VideoLAN team
main debug: revision 2.1.2-0-ga4c4876
main debug: configured with ../extras/package/macosx/../../../configure  '--prefix=/Users/fkuehne/Desktop/videolan/gits/vlc-2.1/release/vlc_install_dir' '--enable-macosx' '--enable-merge-ffmpeg' '--enable-growl' '--enable-faad' '--enable-flac' '--enable-theora' '--enable-shout' '--enable-ncurses' '--enable-twolame' '--enable-realrtsp' '--enable-libass' '--enable-macosx-audio' '--enable-macosx-eyetv' '--enable-macosx-qtkit' '--enable-macosx-vout' '--disable-caca' '--disable-skins2' '--disable-xcb' '--disable-sdl' '--disable-samplerate' '--disable-macosx-dialog-provider' '--with-macosx-sdk=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk' '--build=x86_64-apple-darwin10' '--with-macosx-version-min=10.6' 'build_alias=x86_64-apple-darwin10' 'CC=xcrun clang' 'CXX=xcrun clang++' 'OBJC=xcrun clang'
main debug: processing request item: rtsp://192.168.0.102:1935/techM/dinesh123456789, node: Playlist, skip: 0
main debug: resyncing on rtsp://192.168.0.102:1935/techM/dinesh123456789
main debug: rtsp://192.168.0.102:1935/techM/dinesh123456789 is at 0
main debug: starting playback of the new playlist item
main debug: resyncing on rtsp://192.168.0.102:1935/techM/dinesh123456789
main debug: rtsp://192.168.0.102:1935/techM/dinesh123456789 is at 0
main debug: creating new input thread
main debug: Creating an input for 'rtsp://192.168.0.102:1935/techM/dinesh123456789'
main debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB, in path '/tmp'
main debug: `rtsp://192.168.0.102:1935/techM/dinesh123456789' gives access `rtsp' demux `' path `192.168.0.102:1935/techM/dinesh123456789'
main debug: creating demux: access='rtsp' demux='' location='192.168.0.102:1935/techM/dinesh123456789' file='(null)'
main debug: looking for access_demux module matching "rtsp": 14 candidates
macosx debug: releasing sleep blocker (2042)
live555 debug: version 2013.12.05
live555 debug: RTP subsession 'audio/MPEG4-GENERIC'
main debug: selecting program id=0
live555 debug: RTP subsession 'video/H264'
live555 debug: setup start: 0.000000 stop:0.000000
live555 debug: We have a timeout of 60 seconds
live555 debug: spawned timeout thread
live555 debug: play start: 0.000000 stop:0.000000
main debug: using access_demux module "live555"
main debug: looking for decoder module matching "any": 38 candidates
main debug: using decoder module "faad"
main debug: looking for decoder module matching "any": 38 candidates
avcodec debug: trying to use direct rendering
avcodec debug: allowing 4 thread(s) for decoding
avcodec debug: avcodec codec (H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10)) started
avcodec debug: using frame thread mode with 4 threads
main debug: using decoder module "avcodec"
main debug: looking for packetizer module matching "any": 21 candidates
packetizer_h264 debug: found NAL_SPS (sps_id=0)
packetizer_h264 debug: found NAL_PPS (pps_id=0 sps_id=0)
main debug: using packetizer module "packetizer_h264"
main debug: looking for meta reader module matching "any": 2 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /Users/canvasm/Library/Application Support/org.videolan.vlc/lua/meta/reader
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/lua/meta/reader
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/lua/meta/reader/filename.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/share/lua/meta/reader
main debug: no meta reader modules matched
main debug: `rtsp://192.168.0.102:1935/techM/dinesh123456789' successfully opened
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
live555 debug: tk->rtpSource->hasBeenSynchronizedUsingRTCP()
main error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
faad warning: decoded zero sample
live555 debug: tk->rtpSource->hasBeenSynchronizedUsingRTCP()
main error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 18%
main debug: reusing audio output
main debug: Buffering 18%
main debug: Buffering 18%
main debug: Buffering 18%
main debug: Buffering 18%
main debug: Buffering 18%
main debug: Buffering 18%
main debug: Buffering 18%
main debug: Buffering 18%
main debug: Buffering 18%
main debug: Buffering 18%
main debug: Buffering 18%
main debug: Buffering 18%
main debug: VLC is looking for: 'f32l' 16000 Hz Stereo frame=1 samples/8 bytes
auhal debug: attempting to use device 0
main debug: Buffering 18%
auhal debug: using default audio device 38
auhal debug: found 16 stream formats for stream id 39
auhal debug: Audio device supports PCM mode only
auhal debug: current format is: [44100.000000][mcpl][9][8][1][8][2][32]
auhal debug: layout of AUHAL has 2 channels
auhal debug: selected 2 physical channels for device output
auhal debug: VLC will output: Stereo
auhal debug: we set the AU format: [16000.000000][mcpl][9][8][1][8][2][32]
auhal debug: the actual set AU format is [16000.000000][mcpl][9][8][1][8][2][32]
auhal debug: analog output successfully opened
main debug: output 'f32l' 16000 Hz Stereo frame=1 samples/8 bytes
main debug: looking for audio volume module matching "any": 2 candidates
main debug: using audio volume module "float_mixer"
main debug: input 'f32l' 16000 Hz Stereo frame=1 samples/8 bytes
main debug: looking for audio filter module matching "scaletempo": 14 candidates
main debug: looking for text renderer module matching "any": 3 candidates
main debug: Buffering 36%
scaletempo debug: format: 16000 rate, 2 nch, 4 bps, fl32
scaletempo debug: params: 30 stride, 0.200 overlap, 14 search
scaletempo debug: 1.000 scale, 480.000 stride_in, 480 stride_out, 384 standing, 96 overlap, 224 search, 800 queue, fl32 mode
main debug: using audio filter module "scaletempo"
main debug: conversion: 'f32l'->'f32l' 16000 Hz->16000 Hz Stereo->Stereo
main debug: conversion pipeline complete
main debug: conversion: 'f32l'->'f32l' 16000 Hz->16000 Hz Stereo->Stereo
main debug: conversion pipeline complete
main debug: looking for audio resampler module matching "any": 2 candidates
main debug: Buffering 36%
main debug: Buffering 36%
main debug: Buffering 36%
main debug: using audio resampler module "ugly_resampler"
main debug: End of audio preroll
freetype debug: looking for Arial Unicode MS
main debug: Buffering 55%
main debug: Buffering 55%
main debug: Buffering 55%
main debug: Buffering 55%
freetype debug: found /Library/Fonts/Arial Unicode.ttf
freetype debug: Using Arial Unicode MS as font from file /Library/Fonts/Arial Unicode.ttf
main debug: Buffering 55%
main debug: Buffering 55%
main debug: Buffering 55%
main debug: Buffering 73%
main debug: Buffering 73%
main debug: Buffering 73%
main debug: Buffering 73%
main debug: Buffering 92%
main debug: Buffering 92%
freetype debug: using fontsize: 2
main debug: using text renderer module "freetype"
main debug: looking for video filter2 module matching "any": 54 candidates
main debug: Buffering 92%
main debug: Buffering 92%
main debug: Stream buffering done (1106 ms in 611 ms)
swscale debug: 32x32 chroma: YUVA -> 16x16 chroma: RGBA with scaling using Bicubic (good quality)
main debug: using video filter2 module "swscale"
main debug: looking for video filter2 module matching "any": 54 candidates
macosx debug: releasing old sleep blocker (2042)
macosx debug: prevented sleep through IOKit (6060)
yuvp debug: YUVP to YUVA converter
main debug: using video filter2 module "yuvp"
main debug: Deinterlacing available
main debug: deinterlace 0, mode blend, is_needed 0
main debug: Opening vout display wrapper
main debug: looking for vout display module matching "any": 5 candidates
vout_macosx debug: Quartz Extreme acceleration is active
main debug: looking for vout window nsobject module matching "any": 1 candidates
macosx debug: returning videoview with proposed position x=0, y=0, width=384, height=512
main debug: using vout window nsobject module "macosx"
macosx debug: toggle playlist from state: removed splitview 0, minimized view 0. Sender is 0x0, unhide video view 0
macosx debug: toggle playlist to state: removed splitview 0, minimized view 0
macosx debug: releasing old sleep blocker (6060)
macosx debug: prevented sleep through IOKit (6061)
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 384x512 window
main debug: using vout display module "vout_macosx"
main debug: original format sz 384x512, of (0,0), vsz 384x512, 4cc I420, sar 1:1, msk r0x0 g0x0 b0x0
main debug: removing module "freetype"
main debug: looking for text renderer module matching "any": 3 candidates
freetype debug: looking for Arial Unicode MS
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 927x522 window
freetype debug: found /Library/Fonts/Arial Unicode.ttf
freetype debug: Using Arial Unicode MS as font from file /Library/Fonts/Arial Unicode.ttf
freetype debug: using fontsize: 2
main debug: using text renderer module "freetype"
avcodec debug: using direct rendering
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 927x522 window
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 690x515 window
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 690x515 window
main debug: End of video preroll
main debug: Received first picture
freetype debug: looking for Arial Unicode MS
freetype debug: found /Library/Fonts/Arial Unicode.ttf
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 690x515 window
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 626x513 window
freetype error: Breaking unbreakable line
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 626x513 window
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 626x513 window
main debug: Decoder buffering done in 537 ms
main warning: buffer too late (-107094 us): dropped
main warning: playback way too early (-133745): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2139 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-55930): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-166563): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2665 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-54146): down-sampling
main warning: timing screwed (drift: -109492 us): stopping resampling
main warning: playback way too early (-177364): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2837 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-55203): down-sampling
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 5650 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 5601 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 5601 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 5551 ms)
main warning: timing screwed (drift: -110555 us): stopping resampling
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 5501 ms)
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 626x513 window
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 5451 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 5401 ms)
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 624x513 window
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 624x513 window
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 624x513 window
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 620x513 window
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 620x513 window
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 5412 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 5362 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 5312 ms)
freetype debug: looking for Arial Unicode MS
freetype debug: found /Library/Fonts/Arial Unicode.ttf
freetype error: Breaking unbreakable line
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 620x513 window
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 615x513 window
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 615x513 window
main warning: playback way too early (-160687): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2570 zeroes
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 615x513 window
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 611x513 window
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 611x513 window
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 611x513 window
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 607x512 window
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 607x512 window
main warning: playback way too late (807787): flushing buffers
main debug: inserting 16098 zeroes
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 607x512 window
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 604x512 window
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 604x512 window
freetype debug: looking for Arial Unicode MS
freetype debug: found /Library/Fonts/Arial Unicode.ttf
freetype error: Breaking unbreakable line
main warning: playback too early (-58490): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-172600): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2761 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-52688): down-sampling
main warning: playback too late (60590): up-sampling
main warning: playback too early (-69137): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-164684): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2634 zeroes
main warning: playback too late (69487): up-sampling
main warning: playback too early (-95188): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-127239): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2035 zeroes
main warning: playback way too late (417940): flushing buffers
main debug: inserting 16950 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-57843): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-124101): playing silence
main debug: inserting 1985 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-51275): down-sampling
main warning: playback too late (126828): up-sampling
main debug: resampling stopped (drift: 74073 us)
main warning: playback too early (-43895): down-sampling
main warning: playback too late (122912): up-sampling
main debug: resampling stopped (drift: 122912 us)
main warning: playback too late (70126): up-sampling
main debug: resampling stopped (drift: -33947 us)
main warning: playback too early (-89585): down-sampling
avcodec error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
main debug: resampling stopped (drift: -25984 us)
main warning: playback too early (-74922): down-sampling
main debug: resampling stopped (drift: 16891 us)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 8228 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 8199 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 8171 ms)
main warning: playback too early (-62194): down-sampling
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 7579 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 7530 ms)
main warning: playback way too early (-120600): playing silence
main debug: inserting 1929 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-54345): down-sampling
main warning: playback too late (109052): up-sampling
main debug: resampling stopped (drift: 109052 us)
main warning: playback too late (169942): up-sampling
main warning: playback way too late (229701): flushing buffers
main debug: inserting 17141 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-63024): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-141228): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2259 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-42439): down-sampling
main debug: resampling stopped (drift: 16450 us)
main warning: playback too early (-42586): down-sampling
main debug: resampling stopped (drift: -1407 us)
main warning: playback too early (-59668): down-sampling
main debug: resampling stopped (drift: 28721 us)
main warning: playback too early (-50864): down-sampling
main debug: resampling stopped (drift: -3214 us)
main warning: playback too early (-60000): down-sampling
main debug: resampling stopped (drift: -11958 us)
main warning: playback too early (-70006): down-sampling
main debug: resampling stopped (drift: 24672 us)
main warning: playback too early (-59188): down-sampling
main warning: playback too late (92048): up-sampling
main debug: resampling stopped (drift: 92048 us)
avcodec error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
main warning: playback too late (107307): up-sampling
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 10768 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 10746 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 10646 ms)
main debug: resampling stopped (drift: -24752 us)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 10073 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 10023 ms)
main warning: playback too early (-57170): down-sampling
main debug: resampling stopped (drift: 10041 us)
main warning: playback too early (-75250): down-sampling
main warning: playback too late (105698): up-sampling
main warning: playback too early (-50408): down-sampling
main warning: playback too late (104059): up-sampling
avcodec error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
main warning: playback too early (-71654): down-sampling
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 13044 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 13101 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 13123 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 12552 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 12502 ms)
main warning: playback way too early (-127446): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2039 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-49993): down-sampling
main debug: resampling stopped (drift: 585 us)
main warning: playback too early (-53366): down-sampling
main debug: resampling stopped (drift: -18012 us)
main warning: playback too early (-72169): down-sampling
main debug: resampling stopped (drift: -12892 us)
main warning: playback too early (-60481): down-sampling
main debug: resampling stopped (drift: -26006 us)
main warning: playback too early (-79285): down-sampling
avcodec error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 15489 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 15470 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 15370 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 14800 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 14750 ms)
main warning: playback way too early (-121753): playing silence
main debug: inserting 1948 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-44418): down-sampling
main debug: resampling stopped (drift: 12107 us)
main warning: playback too early (-64057): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-161096): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2577 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-73604): down-sampling
avcodec error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
main warning: playback way too early (-164564): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2633 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-55553): down-sampling
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 17430 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 17466 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 17367 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 16797 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 16748 ms)
main warning: playback way too early (-156252): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2500 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-71955): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-137605): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2201 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-69374): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-126830): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2029 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-94307): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-139918): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2238 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-45043): down-sampling
main warning: timing screwed (drift: -94061 us): stopping resampling
main warning: playback way too early (-140133): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2242 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-57091): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-142632): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2282 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-97793): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-142149): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2274 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-82665): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-140611): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2249 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-78918): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-146588): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2345 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-48695): down-sampling
main warning: timing screwed (drift: -99647 us): stopping resampling
main warning: playback way too early (-141697): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2267 zeroes
avcodec error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
main warning: playback too early (-56127): down-sampling
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 18275 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 18175 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 18155 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 17255 ms)
main warning: playback way too early (-137497): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2199 zeroes
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 17382 ms)
main warning: playback too early (-45030): down-sampling
main warning: timing screwed (drift: -116149 us): stopping resampling
main warning: playback too early (-103380): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-242758): playing silence
main debug: inserting 3884 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-93712): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-125636): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2010 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-56963): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-152006): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2432 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-54735): down-sampling
main warning: timing screwed (drift: -114240 us): stopping resampling
main warning: playback way too early (-134557): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2152 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-60472): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-138838): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2221 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-79977): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-141906): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2270 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-78887): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-123251): playing silence
main debug: inserting 1972 zeroes
avcodec error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
main warning: playback too early (-79824): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-124871): playing silence
main debug: inserting 1997 zeroes
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 18756 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 18657 ms)
main warning: playback too early (-61224): down-sampling
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 18646 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 17996 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 18025 ms)
main warning: playback way too early (-165004): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2640 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-54950): down-sampling
main warning: timing screwed (drift: -112057 us): stopping resampling
main warning: playback way too early (-126052): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2016 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-80645): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-123712): playing silence
main debug: inserting 1979 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-71634): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-163325): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2613 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-46892): down-sampling
main warning: timing screwed (drift: -101665 us): stopping resampling
main warning: playback too early (-113667): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-124474): playing silence
main debug: inserting 1991 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-61353): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-141988): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2271 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-65687): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-149182): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2386 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-57925): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-147798): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2364 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-49201): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-138953): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2223 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-92710): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-126408): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2022 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-49020): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-138542): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2216 zeroes
main warning: playback too early (-59855): down-sampling
main warning: playback way too early (-148224): playing silence
main debug: inserting 2371 zeroes
main error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 1000 ms)
main error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
live555 warning: no data received in 10s, eof ?
main debug: EOF reached
main debug: Stream buffering done (0 ms in 3621 ms)
main debug: Decoder buffering done in 0 ms
main debug: finished input
main debug: removing module "faad"
main debug: killing decoder fourcc `mp4a', 0 PES in FIFO
main debug: removing module "ugly_resampler"
main debug: removing module "scaletempo"
macosx debug: releasing sleep blocker (6061)
main debug: removing module "float_mixer"
main debug: keeping audio output
main debug: removing module "avcodec"
avcodec debug: ffmpeg codec (H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10)) stopped
main debug: killing decoder fourcc `h264', 0 PES in FIFO
main debug: saving a free vout
main debug: reusing provided vout
main debug: removing module "packetizer_h264"
main debug: removing module "live555"
main debug: Program doesn't contain anymore ES
main debug: dead input
main debug: changing item without a request (current 0/1)
main debug: nothing to play
main debug: destroying useless vout
main debug: removing module "vout_macosx"
main debug: removing module "freetype"
main debug: removing module "yuvp"
main debug: removing module "swscale"
macosx debug: toggle playlist from state: removed splitview 0, minimized view 0. Sender is 0x0, unhide video view 0
macosx debug: toggle playlist to state: removed splitview 0, minimized view 0
macosx debug: releasing sleep blocker (6061)
```

Comment: Any RTSP expert out there who can let me know why it is happening and provide me some hint for a possible solution for the same,

Comment: Run `VLC` in verbose mode `-vvv` and fetch the contents of the `SDP` (it's dumped at some point in the console) for the case when you have both A/V streams and only the audio plays and post it in your question.

Comment: Hi aergistal.. no idea how to run the vlc in verbose mode can you help? I am using a mac machine and vlc is installed as an application

Comment: Try `Tools->Messages`. You can set the verbosity level there.

Comment: Hi aergistal.. i have updated the log with vlc message output.. (There is no option for setting the verbosity level on mac though) i am seeing some issues like video is late by 5 seconds and dropped but no idea how to fix this.

Comment: That log is pretty verbose, maybe you should post it to pastebin instead cause it kills the question. What are you using to capture the desktop/mic and send it to Wowza? Can you post the full commands?

Comment: Aergistal, I have no idea of pastebin and how to use it. I am writing my own encoder for RTSP. What i am doing is taking screenshots at 20 fps and capture the mic output buffer (using mac avcapture API's) than i add the required data and headers needed for RTSP broadcast and send the audio video packets to Wowza.